# How to decode bytes calldata in a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, rsk

I have 2 interacting smart contracts which I am developing/testing in [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) and deploying to [RSK](https://developers.rsk.co/). One of them is an [ERC1363 payable token](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1363) with `transferAndCall(address,uint256,bytes)` function, and the second one is a token receiver whose `buy(address,uint,uint,bytes3)` function call I need to encode off-chain and send to the token's `transferAndCall` function `bytes` parameter. The ERC1363 contract transfers tokens from sender's account to the receiver smart contract's account and then within the same transaction calls receiver's `onTransferReceived(address,address,uint256,bytes)`, where the last `bytes` parameter should be encoded `buy` function call.

This is my receiver smart contract:

```
contract TokenReceiver is IERC1363Receiver {
  IERC1363 acceptedToken;
    
  constructor(IERC1363 _acceptedToken) {
    acceptedToken = _acceptedToken;
  }
  event PurchaseMade(address indexed sender, uint tokensPaid, uint productAmount, bytes3 color);
    
  function buy(address sender, uint tokensPaid, uint productAmount, bytes3 color) public {
    // allowed to be called only via the accepted token
    require(msg.sender == address(acceptedToken), "I accept purchases in Payable Tokens");
    emit PurchaseMade(sender, tokensPaid, productAmount, color);
  }

  function onTransferReceived(address operator, address sender, uint256 tokensPaid, bytes calldata data) external override (IERC1363Receiver) returns (bytes4) {
      // TODO: decode calldata and call `buy` function
    return this.onTransferReceived.selector;
  }
}
```

This is how I assemble the calldata by encoding the signature and params of the `buy` function together:

```js
  it('buyer should be able to pay tokens and buy products in one transaction', async () => {
    // TokenReceiver `buy` function signature hash: 0x85f16ff4
    const buySigHash = tokenReceiver.interface.getSighash('buy');
    // providing some product properties to the TokenReceiver
    const productAmount = 99;
    const color = '0x121212';
    // packing `buy` signature and the properties together
    const calldata = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
      ['bytes4', 'uint256', 'bytes3'],
      [buySigHash, productAmount, color],
    );
    // pay tokens and buy some products in one tx
    const transferAndCallTx = payableToken
      .connect(buyer)
      ['transferAndCall(address,uint256,bytes)'](tokenReceiver.address, tokenAmount, calldata);
    await expect(transferAndCallTx)
      .to.emit(tokenReceiver, 'PurchaseMade');
  });
```

My question is:

- How do I decode the calldata inside the receiver's `onTransferReceived` function?
- How do I extract the function signature and the other 2 encoded params, and then call the corresponding function on the receiver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
//Define struct within the contract, but outside the function
struct BuyParams {
        bytes4 buySigHash;
        uint256 productAmount;
        bytes3 color;
}

// within onTransferReceived: decode the calldata:
BuyParams memory decoded = abi.decode(
    data,
    (BuyParams)
);


//Now use as function arguments by passing:
decoded.buySigHash,
decoded.productAmount,
decoded.color,
```

Addition:
You might be able to save gas by changing the order of the calldata:

```
from:
        bytes4 buySigHash;
        uint256 productAmount;
        bytes3 color;
to:
        uint256 productAmount;
        bytes4 buySigHash;
        bytes3 color;
```

Comment: Thanks, brilliant idea! Let's say, now I have a function signature and the params. How can I then call a function with a dynamic name (decoded signature)? Is it possible to do smth like `buySigHash(productAmount, color, ...);` ?

Comment: try: ```this.call(buySigHash, productAmount, color, ...)```

Comment: sorry made a small mistake, did you try ```address(this).call()```?

Answer (score 7):

You could make use of inline assembly to decode your bytes data. Create a `pure` helper function with the following contents:
​

```
function decode(bytes memory data) private pure returns(bytes4 selector, uint productAmount, bytes3 color) {
    assembly {
      // load 32 bytes into `selector` from `data` skipping the first 32 bytes
      selector := mload(add(data, 32))
      productAmount := mload(add(data, 64))
      color := mload(add(data, 96))
    }
}
```

​
here `mload(0xAB)` loads a word (32 bytes)  located at the memory address 0xAB, and `add(0xAB, 0xCD)` summs two values
​
See [this article](https://medium.com/shyft-network-media/solidity-and-inline-assembly-37871dc582a6) for more on inline assembly in solidity.
​
Next, this is how you can utilise the created function in you contract:
​

```
(bytes4 selector, uint productAmount, bytes3 color) =
  decode(data);
```

​
Since you have the selector and other parameters, you can construct the function call data
​

```
bytes memory funcData =
  abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, sender, tokensPaid, productAmount, color);
```

​
Now you can make a low level call to invoke the corresponding function
​

```
(bool success,) = address(this).call(funcData);
require(success, "call failed");
```

​
**Warning**:
Keep in mind that using the above method
allows an attacker to be able to call **any function** in your contract.
Be careful using low level calls.
​
To avoid this, validate the function selector,
before calling it, like this:
​

```
if (selector == this.buy.selector) {
    buy(sender, tokensPaid, productAmount, color);
}
```

​
Thus, your `onTransferReceived` function may look something like this:
​

```
function onTransferReceived(address operator, address sender, uint256 tokensPaid, bytes calldata data) external override (IERC1363Receiver) returns (bytes4) {
    require(msg.sender == address(acceptedToken), "I accept purchases in Payable Tokens");
​
    (bytes4 selector, uint productAmount, bytes3 color) =
        decode(data);
​
    if (selector == this.buy.selector) {
      buy(sender, tokensPaid, productAmount, color);
    }
​
    return this.onTransferReceived.selector;
  }
```